# achartengine: getZoomRate always returns 1.5?

Tags: android, charts, zooming, achartengine

I have a TimeChart and I'm trying to save the zoom rate whenever it is changed.
Therefore I add a ZoomListener to my chart:

```
    public void showChart()
        {
            mChartView = ChartFactory.getTimeChartView(this.context, this.mDataset,
 this.mRenderer, TrackedValue.DATE_FORMAT_USER);

            this.layout.addView(mChartView);

            mChartView.setZoomRate(prefs.getChartZoomRate());
            Log.d("showChart", "Set: "+prefs.getChartZoomRate());

            mChartView.addZoomListener(new ZoomListener() {

                @Override
                public void zoomReset() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void zoomApplied(ZoomEvent e) {              
                    prefs.setChartZoomRate(e.getZoomRate());
                    Log.d("zoomApplied", "Save: "+String.valueOf(e.getZoomRate()+", isZoomIn: "+e.isZoomIn()));
                }
            }, true, true);
        }
```

When I see the chart and press the Zoom-In button, the output of my Log is:

```
zoomApplied Save: 1.5, isZoomIn: true
```

When I zoom out (via the zoom button), the log output is:

```
zoomApplied Save 1.5, isZoomIn: false
```

No matter how often I zoom in or out, I don't get why the e.getZoomRate() always returns 1.5, no matter what the actual zoom rate is... 
The e.isZoomIn() is working fine though.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I have just tried the AChartEngine demo program and called the line below and it displays me the correct 1.2 value:

```
  mChartView.setZoomRate(1.2f);
```

Please make sure you are setting the correct value.